# Multiple 301 Redirect For Multiple Pages or URL

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I am redesigning my store and so the old structure has been changed with the new structure. So trying to redirect all old products with the new.

I have more than 20-25 products and if I write redirect rule for every product than I have to write in this way

```
Redirect 301 /store/products/somename/ http://store.domain.com/nicecar
Redirect 301 /store/products/blabla/ http://store.domain.com/newpros
Redirect 301 /store/products/cubacuba/ http://store.domain.com/illollo
```

Which will become to long and may slow down the site. So is there anyway to optimize this redirect rule?

Thanks a lot

Comment: if you access to A[ache config, you should use `RewriteMap`.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. I may have access from cPanel. But I don't know and how to do. Could you please help me to do?

Comment: Ok I will provide an example in my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is better to use [**`RewriteMap`**](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritemap) for your requirement. Here is an example how to use it:

1. Add following line to your `httpd.conf` file:

   ```
   RewriteMap prodMap txt://path/to/prodMap.txt
   ```
2. Create a text file as `/path/to/prodMap.txt` like this:

   ```
   somename nicecar
   blabla newpros
   ```
3. Add these line in your .htaccess file under `DOCUMENT_ROOT`:

   ```
   Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
   RewriteEngine on

   RewriteRule ^store/products/([^/]+)/?$ http://store.domain.com/${prodMap:$1} [L,R=301,NC]
   ```

Comment: Thanks Anubhava, I am checking for httpd.conf access. give me sometime get back to you.. thanks again for your help

Comment: Damn! I think I don't have access to httpd.conf. Any other way to do?

Comment: Hmm in absence of that only way to avoid multiple rewrite rules is to handle it via some script (e.g. PHP)

Comment: :( so this mean quick way is only adding line for every pages? Will that affect site speed?

Comment: For now I think 21 pages

Comment: Oh 21 is nothing, feel free to create 21 rules. Even hundred of them is also fine, won't affect speed.

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to the vhost or server config, you can setup a [rewrite map](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritemap), though in reality, it's probably marginally faster than just having a ton of redirects. The redirects that you have in your htaccess file are cached, so as long as the htaccess file isn't modified, the directives don't need to be re-read.

There's a very detailed tutorial for how to use RewriteMap and the many various mappings you can use with it.