# How to redirect multiple unique urls with 301

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I've read this: [Multiple 301 Redirect For Multiple Pages or URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18877075/multiple-301-redirect-for-multiple-pages-or-url)

but my URLs contain a timestamp in the URL (damn Wordpress) and I need to redirect each one manually. I'm migrating a blog from Wordpress to a new Expressionengine install.

for instance: I need http://iwantrest.com/2014/04/29/counting-the-cost-of-justice/ to forward to http://iwantrest.com/blog/post/counting-the-cost-of-justice/

The below won't work but I can't make the map modular because of the timestamp.

```
Redirect 301 2014/04/29/counting-the-cost-of-justice/ http://iwantrest.com/blog/post/counting-the-cost-of-justice/
```

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `RedirectMatch` for its Regex capabilities:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/[0-9]{4}/[0-9]{2}/[0-9]{2}/([^/]+)/?$ /blog/post/$1/
```