# Mapping a large redirection list

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, seo, virtualhost

For migration and SEO reasons I need to force redirections for a large list of URLS.

Something like:

```
Redirect 301 /old/00001.jpg /new/00001_{UNIXTIMESTAMP}_{name}.jpg
...
Redirect 301 /old/99999.jpg /new/99999_{UNIXTIMESTAMP}_{name}.jpg
```

Also need constantly edit these lines as you can see in the structure. So the question is, which is the preferred way to include all these directives that are changing dynamically?

I'm using apache.

Comment: Answer - [Multiple 301 Redirect For Multiple Pages or URL](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18877268/6416584)

Comment: @Emily very useful, thanks!