# ASP>NET page redirect 301

Tags: asp.net, url-rewriting

I want to write an asp.net page redirect

this URL

https://mysiteurl/mystore/storename/about-the-store

should always redirect to

https://mysiteurl/mystore/storename

about-the-store page exists but we don't want to delete it.
we have multiple stores and every store has the about-the-store page.

Similarly

https://mysiteurl/mystore/storename1/about-the-store

should always redirect to

https://mysiteurl/mystore/storename1

I need this redirect happen even if user types the complete about-the-store URL in the browser and it should be a 301 redirect.

This rule would be for stores only, for example rule should only redirect if "mystore" is available in the URL.

There is no limit of how many stores will be in my application.

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure maps and rules for rewriting in IIS manager. Open IIS manager, find your site and navigate to "URL Rewrite".

In depth documentation for this procedure can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/using-rewrite-maps-in-url-rewrite-module).

Once you've created a rewrite map specifing the new URL with which to replace the old URL, something like the following should appear in your web.config file:

```
 <rewriteMaps>
 <rewriteMap name=”Redirects”>
 <add key=”/mystore/storename/about-the-store” value=”/mystore/storename” />
 <add key=”/mystore/storename1/about-the-store” value=”/mystore/storename1” />
 </rewriteMap>
 </rewriteMaps>
```

Here we are essentially providing asp.net with the new location of our page and performing a 301 redirect from the old URL to the new one.

To keep things clean you can add a new file to the root of your project called 'redirect.config' and copy and paste the above into the file then add this to your web.config file under system.webServer:

```
<rewrite>
<rewriteMaps configSource=”redirect.config” />
<rules>
<rule name=”Redirect Rules”>
<match url=”.*” />
<conditions>
<add input=”{Redirects:{REQUEST_URI}}” pattern=”(.+)” />
</conditions>
<action type=”Redirect” url=”{C:1}” />
</rule>
</rules>
</rewrite>
```

Here we are pointing web.config to our redirect.config file and passing the parameters or 'rules' needed to make the URL switches.

Comment: redirect.config contains name of stores but in my case there would be thousands of stores, so I can't add entries in a config file like that.

Comment: In this case I believe rewrite map is still your best hope. You should be able to customize the parameters to suit your needs. Perhaps this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18877075/multiple-301-redirect-for-multiple-pages-or-url) can be of some help? Good luck.